# Calculate the x and y coordinate around a pivot point

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, rotation

I have a girl character who stands at (in this example) x:500 and y: 200.

[image]

In my Javascript game I need to route another character to be within 100 pixels to her left. However the girl character might be standing in the corner of a room. In which case I need to calculate what the next x and y co-ordinate would be if we rotated 20 degrees lower from the girl standing at x:500 and y: 200 but still 100 pixels away from the girl character.

What is the name of this type of calculation?

Comment: It's a basic circle. `y: Math.sin(angle) * dist + Cy, x: Math.cos(angle) * dist + Cx`, where `Cx` and `Cy` are the current coordinates of the girl (centre point), and `dist = 100` according to your example (radius).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is polar coordinates (radius and angle). Converting between `x, y` and `radius, angle` is done using

```
r = sqrt(x^2, y^2)
a = atan(y,x)
x = cos(a)*r
y = sin(a)*r
```

The algorithm below starts at the girl's position, subtracts the polar coordinate and sees if it can return. Otherwise, add 20 degrees and continue.

```
function to_polar(x, y) {
  return [Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y), Math.atan2(y, x)]
}

function from_polar(r, a) {
  return [Math.cos(a) * r, Math.sin(a) * r]
}

function get_other(girl) {
  let r = 100

  for (let degree = 0; degree < 360; degree += 20) {
    let mod = from_polar(r, degree * 180 / Math.PI)
    let other = [girl[0] - mod[0], girl[1] - mod[1]]
    if (is_not_inside_of_wall(other)) {
      return other
    }
  }
  console.log("couldn't find any position :(")
}

let girl = [500, 200]
let other = get_other(girl)
console.log(other)
```

`get_other` correctly returns `[ 400, 200 ]` on the first iteration